# Wrong return of Roman Numeral Converter

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have no idea why does my function return undefined. Can you explain me how does this work?
I thought that at the beginning of the loop function i pass number and array, then it checks if number is 0, it is not so next is for loop. Inside loop i have if statement that check if after subtracing object value from passed numer is bigger than 0. If it is then I push the corresponding key. After that I use loop function again. So I thought it should go like this for num = 6

loop(6,[]) => loop(1,['V']) => loop(0,['V','I'] end,
but instead i got this
[ 'V',
'I',
'IV',
'I',
'I',
'I',
'V',
'IV',
'I',
'I',
'IV',
'I',
'I',
'I',
'I' ]

Where is the problem?

```js
const lookup = {
  M: 1000,
  CM: 900,
  D: 500,
  CD: 400,
  C: 100,
  XC: 90,
  L: 50,
  XL: 40,
  X: 10,
  IX: 9,
  V: 5,
  IV: 4,
  I: 1
}
const loop = (num, arr) => {
  if (num === 0) return arr
  for (let key in lookup) {
    if (num - lookup[key] >= 0) {
      arr.push(key)
      loop(num - lookup[key], arr)
    }
  }
}
console.log(loop(6, []))
```

Comment: You do not `return` anything if the cases where you recursively call `loop`. You probably need `return arr` after the `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `return` for the base case (`num===0`) but you don't `return` the
recursive case!

Since you don't return anything for the general recursive case, the function default return is `undefined`.

Just return the recursive call output:

```js
const lookup = {
  M: 1000,
  CM: 900,
  D: 500,
  CD: 400,
  C: 100,
  XC: 90,
  L: 50,
  XL: 40,
  X: 10,
  IX: 9,
  V: 5,
  IV: 4,
  I: 1
}
const loop = (num, arr) => {
  if (num === 0) return arr
  for (let key in lookup) {
    if (num - lookup[key] >= 0) {
      arr.push(key)
      return loop(num - lookup[key], arr)
    }
  }
}
console.log(loop(6, []))
```

Comment: Thank you for help, that is right.

Comment: @Randomuser if you think this is the answer mark it so other people will know you got the solution.

Comment: had to wait for a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues I noted here.

1. As soon as you find one match, you should break from the loop.
2. At the end, you should be returning `arr`. If you are not returning anything when you do `console.log`, it will show undefined.

```
const lookup = {
  M: 1000,
  CM: 900,
  D: 500,
  CD: 400,
  C: 100,
  XC: 90,
  L: 50,
  XL: 40,
  X: 10,
  IX: 9,
  V: 5,
  IV: 4,
  I: 1
}
const loop = (num, arr) => {
  if (num === 0) return arr
  for (let key in lookup) {
    if (num - lookup[key] >= 0) {
      arr.push(key)
      loop(num - lookup[key], arr)
      break
    }
  }
  return arr
}
console.log(loop(6, []))
```